# send an email with content that can not be edited

Tags: android, email

I make an application that allows users to send an email. when i use the usual procedure to send an email with intents the user is redirected to gmail app, and he can edit the mail. I would like to prevent the user from modifying the content of the email. would anyone know how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so I am posting the answer.  The short answer is that if you rely on the user's phone as the email client, then there is no guaranteed way to prevent the user from editing the email message, because the Gmail app is out of your control.  So, what you should instead do here is to use a server side webapp to send the message instead.  As an example, I have used an email service (e.g. HawkHost) on the server side behind an Android app to send the message.  With this setup, you can completely control what message gets sent from the user or on behalf of the user.